# The integral of the Dickman function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, number-theory

It is well known that the integration of the [Dickman function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function) with the weight $\frac{1}{(t+2)}$ or $\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}$ gives  [Golomb – Dickman constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb%E2%80%93Dickman_constant) :

$$\lambda=  \int_0^\infty \frac{\rho(t)}{t+2}\,dt$$
or
$$\lambda=  \int_0^\infty \frac{\rho(t)}{(1+t)^2}\,dt,$$

Where $\lambda=0.624...$ - Golomb–Dickman constant, $\rho(t)$ - Dickman function.

But what about the integral of the Dickman function itself $\int_0^\infty \rho(t)dt= $?

I tried to integrate numerically with the help of  [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) using its function DickmanRho(t). At the limit of accuracy, I got the value $1.7811$, which, within the error, coincides with **$ e^{\gamma} $**, where $\gamma=0.5772...$ - [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).This result is not unexpected considering  [Mertens' third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems), **but how this result сan be proved based on the definition of the Dickman function** i.e. through delay differential equation with initial conditions(Definition see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function))?

Comment: I just found [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.1856.pdf) discussing this result: "The key relation of the Dickman function to Euler’s constant is that it has total mass $e^{\gamma}$, p.40

Comment: Laplace transform is all you need